# Docker crashes when mysql server is initialized

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a docker setup for run a php 8.1 environment with mysql and phpmyadmin.

Until now, I had no problems when running the container. However, since a few days, I have the following error in the console:

```
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30 12:42:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
web-server_1    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
web-server_1    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
web-server_1    | [Mon Jan 30 12:42:29.746057 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) PHP/8.1.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
web-server_1    | [Mon Jan 30 12:42:29.746168 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
phpmyadmin_1    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
phpmyadmin_1    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
phpmyadmin_1    | [Mon Jan 30 12:42:29.955832 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.53 (Debian) PHP/8.0.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
phpmyadmin_1    | [Mon Jan 30 12:42:29.957285 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30 12:42:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30 12:42:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
mysql-server_1  | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:33.480281Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:33.492161Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 1
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:33.507564Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:33.581466Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:33.873051Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012585] [InnoDB] Linux Native AIO interface is not supported on this platform. Please check your OS documentation and install appropriate binary of InnoDB.
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:33.873457Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012654] [InnoDB] Linux Native AIO disabled.
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:36.560005Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:36.896688Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013021] [InnoDB] A transaction id in a record of table `mysql`.`schemata` is newer than the system-wide maximum.
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:36.905473Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013021] [InnoDB] A transaction id in a record of table `mysql`.`tablespaces` is newer than the system-wide maximum.
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:36.905625Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013021] [InnoDB] A transaction id in a record of table `mysql`.`tablespaces` is newer than the system-wide maximum.
mysql-server_1  | 2023-01-30T12:42:36Z UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
mysql-server_1  | Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
mysql-server_1  | BuildID[sha1]=6b049f17400f850658b2eb3ff165ec9a085d9655
mysql-server_1  | Thread pointer: 0x6a28450
mysql-server_1  | Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
mysql-server_1  | where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
mysql-server_1  | terribly wrong...
mysql-server_1  | stack_bottom = 400fcf3be0 thread_stack 0x100000
mysql-server_1  | /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x213de91]
mysql-server_1  | /usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x387) [0xfdeac7]
mysql-server_1  | /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0xa5) [0xfdeb85]
mysql-server_1  | /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x12d00) [0x4000a47d00]
mysql-server_1  | /usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::sync_meta_data(THD*)+0x493) [0x1ee1bd3]
mysql-server_1  | /usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::restart(THD*)+0xfa) [0x1ee332a]
mysql-server_1  | /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x2109f71]
mysql-server_1  | /usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::upgrade_57::do_pre_checks_and_initialize_dd(THD*)+0xc70) [0x21107b0]
mysql-server_1  | /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x10a58e6]
mysql-server_1  | /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x290c7f9]
mysql-server_1  | /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x81da) [0x4000a3d1da]
mysql-server_1  | /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x40023f0e73]
mysql-server_1  | 
mysql-server_1  | Trying to get some variables.
mysql-server_1  | Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
mysql-server_1  | Query (0): Connection ID (thread ID): 1
mysql-server_1  | Status: NOT_KILLED
mysql-server_1  | 
mysql-server_1  | The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
mysql-server_1  | information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
mysql-server_1 exited with code 2
```

Here is my file structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABfBR.png)

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web-server:
    build: web-server
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/30-custom.ini
      - /Users/<myname>/documents/web:/var/www/html/
    networks:
      - static-network
    environment:
      - XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/tmp
  phpmyadmin:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mysql-server
      - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=*******
    networks:
      - static-network
  mysql-server:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /Users/<myname>/documents/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=*******
    networks:
      - static-network
networks:
  static-network:
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libc-client-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        unzip \
        libmagickwand-dev \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) zip intl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) exif \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
    
RUN printf "\n" | pecl install imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick

# Enable Apache mod_rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite
    
# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY conf/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/z-app.conf
RUN a2enconf z-app

RUN usermod --non-unique --uid 1000 www-data
```

Does anyone know where this is coming from?

I also tried to launch a local server with MAMP, I also have an error that tells me:
"Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration."

Comment: Are you running Docker in WSL? There is a bug there:  https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3631

Comment: @Yuyu did you fix this? Or anybody?